# Error on creating a folder in SSIS MSDB

Tags: ssis, directory

I'm trying to create a folder for my SSIS packages like I've done on several servers up to now.
But instead of the folder being created, I recieve the following error: `SSIS folder 'XXX' already exists in the specified parent folder. (Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0)`
I've tried using several diffrent names but have recieved the same error each time.

This is a new instance of SSIS that I set up today, so I'm very sure no other folders exist.

Comment: What if you manually call the stored procedure to create the folder `EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_ssis_addfolder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the culprit!

At first I tried the solution suggested by @billinkc in the comment, it worked (I managed to create a folder) but the folder wasn't usable as I couldn't upload packages.

I have db_owner permission on the MSDB database and so I can see and access the SSIS MSDB folder.
What I really needed was the db_ssisadmin permission. Not to worry as db_owner permissions allow me to give myself the db_ssisadmin permission!

After this was done, all the problems (the one in the original Q and more) disappeared.